# I am getting the following error , line 25:8: Column 'flag1' cannot be resolved

Tags: sql, presto

I wrote the following query in presto,which gave the error :line 25:8: Column 'flag1' cannot be resolved. The flag condition has to be incorporated. I had run a similar query on redshift without any issue.

```sql
select dt,CASE WHEN date_diff ('day',fod,dt) <= 28 then 'New' ELSE 'Old'
                   END AS flag1,COUNT(us.user_id) AS users,SUM(views) AS o_views,SUM(orders) AS orderss
FROM
(
 (select dt,user_id,portfolio_views as views ,portfolio_orders as orders
FROM gold.user_daily_osv
 ) AS us
JOIN
(select user_id,CAST(first_order_ts as DATE) as fod
from gold.prism__user_master_bi
) as um
ON
us.user_id=um.user_id)
 WHERE flag1 = 'New'
group by 1,2
order by 1 desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider changing `WHERE flag1 = 'New'` to `WHERE date_diff ('day',fod,dt) <= 28`

```sql
SELECT
    dt,
    CASE 
        WHEN date_diff ('day',fod,dt) <= 28 then 'New' 
        ELSE 'Old' 
    END AS flag1,
    COUNT(us.user_id) AS users,
    SUM(views) AS o_views,
    SUM(orders) AS orderss 
FROM ( 
    (
    select 
        dt,
        user_id,
        portfolio_views as views ,
        portfolio_orders as orders 
    FROM 
        gold.user_daily_osv 
    ) AS us 
    JOIN (
           select 
               user_id,
               CAST(first_order_ts as DATE) as fod 
           from gold.prism__user_master_bi 
    ) as um ON us.user_id=um.user_id
) 
WHERE date_diff ('day',fod,dt) <= 28 
group by 1,2 
order by 1 desc
```

Comment: This filter gives a values for "new". If I replace  WHERE date_diff ('day',fod,dt) <= 28 with WHERE date_diff ('day',fod,dt) >= 28,it gives "new" as well as "old" values. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you even bother defining the flag?  You could just use:

```
SELECT udo.dt, 'New' as flag1,
       COUNT(*) AS users,
       SUM(udo.portfolio_views) AS o_views,
       SUM(udo.portfolio_orders) AS orderss 
FROM gold.user_daily_osv udo JOIN
     gold.prism__user_master_bi um
     ON us.user_id = um.user_id
WHERE date_diff('day', CAST(um.first_order_ts as DATE), udo.dt) <= 28 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Notes:

- Use table aliases so the query is easier to write and read.
- There is no need for subqueries.
- I prefer direct date comparisons to using `date_diff()`, but I left the `date_diff()` in your code.
- `COUNT()` works without a column.  There is no need to count the number of non-`NULL` values of a column.  Just use `COUNT(*)`.  Or if you prefer, `COUNT(1)`.